# Printing File external files

Tags: excel, vba

The prints of files are from cell value of column A to a single network printer (NE03:), Now i want to print files parallel from Column B to another attached printer (NE05:)

Excel File Format:

```
Column 'A'-------------Column 'B'
C:\test\gear.pdf-------C:\invoice\chan.pdf
C:\test\court.pdf------C:\tyo\dated.pdf
...
```

Will some help me to modify the codes so i can print on 2 printers consecutively one from Column A to printer HP LaserJet Professional M1213nf MFP and from Column B to printer HP LaserJet P1106.

```
    Sub PrintPDFFiles() 
    zProg = "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" 
    zLastRow = [a65536].End(xlUp).Row 
    temp = "a1:a" & zLastRow 
    zPrinter = "HP LaserJet Professional M1213nf MFP " 
    For Each cell In Range(temp) 
    zFile = cell.Value 
    If zFile Like "*.pdf" Then 
    Shell """" & zProg & """/n /t """ & zFile & """" 
    End If 
    Next 
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using Excel 2003. You should never hard code values like `65536`. You can get undesirable results in xl2007+ as they have `1048576` rows.

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

```
Option Explicit
'~~> Printer names
Const Prin1 As String = "HP LaserJet Professional M1213nf MFP"
Const Prin2 As String = "HP LaserJet P1106"
Const AcroPath As String = "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"

Private Declare Function SetDefaultPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" _
Alias "SetDefaultPrinterA" (ByVal pszPrinter As String) As Long

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i  As Long
    Dim prt As String

    '~~> Get current default printer
    prt = Application.ActivePrinter

    '~~> Set this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Get last row of col A
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Set default printer
        SetDefaultPrinter Prin1

        '~~> Print from Col A first
        For i = 1 To lRow
            Shell """" & AcroPath & """/n /t """ & .Range("A" & i).Value & """"
            DoEvents
        Next i

        '~~> Get last row of col B
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Set default printer
        SetDefaultPrinter Prin2

        '~~> Print from Col B Next
        For i = 1 To lRow
            Shell """" & AcroPath & """/n /t """ & .Range("B" & i).Value & """"
            DoEvents
        Next i
    End With

    SetDefaultPrinter prt
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Rout, I tested it's working, Still a small change to it is required it prints the column 'A' competely & then shifts to Column 'B' instead of that is it possible to shift alternate after every row. Starting Col A2 then Col B2 next Col A3, B3 this will print consecutively/parallel at a time saving time as i have lot of printing.

Comment: It worked? LOL! kool :) Yes it is possible what you are asking but it will slow down your code. becuase, you will be changing the printer in the loop. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Yes, If it's possible i will give a try to both.

Comment: Siddharth, Pl. provide 2nd update. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and if stuck, post the code that you tried? It's rather easy to do that if you understand the above code.